# Known conditions to make $A \otimes B$ be pos.def., even if $A$ is not pos.def.?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, positive-definite

Are there conditions that I should demand to be sure that $A \otimes B$ is positive definite, even when allowing $A$ not being positive definite, while $B$ is positive definite?

Comment: I suppose $A$ and $B$ could both be negative definite.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for the comment. I forgot the $B$ matrix must be pos.def. , and edited the question accordingly. I'm sorry for my error,.

Comment: In this context, does positive definite mean symmetric?

Comment: Assuming positive definite means symmetric here: If $B$ is positive definite, then $A \otimes B$ will be positive definite if and only if $A$ is also positive definite.